# Rails - redirect user back to the original action after a signin before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I have a `jobs` model and a link to create a new job. I would like to force a user to sign in before visiting the new job form. I have set up a before_action that forces sign in.

**application_controller.rb**

```
  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :require_signin!

  def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_signin!
    if current_user.nil?
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
before_action :require_signin!, only: [:new]
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/auth/twitter' => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to user, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end
end
```

**Current behavior**
When a user, who is not signed in, clicks the 'jobs/new' link, the chain of events is `jobs#new` -> `login` -> `user` (default redirect after signing in). User then must navigate back to `jobs#new`

**Desired behavior**
When a user, who is not signed in, clicks the 'jobs/new' link, the chain of events is `jobs#new` -> `login` -> `jobs#new`.

I know the before_action is intercepting the original action, but I would like to complete the original action after signing in. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this, you can save the original route in session before redirecting to sign_in route, like:

```
class JobsController
  before_action :save_original_path, only: [:new]
  before_action :require_signin!, only: [:new]

  private

  def save_original_path
    session[:return_to] = new_job_path
  end
end
```

and

```
class SessionsController
  def create
    ...
    redirect_to (session[:return_to] || user), :notice => "Signed in!"
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! One typo to correct for potential future readers: session[:return_to] should point to new_job_path, not new_jobs_path.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Updated it.